# how to share a calculated variable between all instances of a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, static-methods, class-variables

I want to calculate a value in the class that stays the same for all instances of that class and is calculated only once

```
class A:
    a = calculate_a()
    def calculate_a():
        return 5
```

first, What should I set as reference for `calculate_a()` in `a = calculate_a()` ?
`self.calculate_a()` and `A.calculate_a()` both are not correct (unresolved reference)
what I need is, when the second instance is created, the `calculate_a()` is not called again.

```
instance1 = A()  -> calls calculate_a() to set value for a;
instance2 = A()  -> uses the value of a calculated above without calling calculate_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Class members are only initialized once - they are initialized *before* (and without) instances being created.

---

You can test this yourself:

```
def calculate_a():
    print("Calculated")
    return 5

class A:   
    a = calculate_a()
```

Executing this prints `'Calculated'` once, even without any creation of instances.

```
def calculate_a():
    print("Calculated")
    return 5

class A:   
    a = calculate_a()

input("Order?")
k = A()
i = A()
c = A()
```

Executing this print's `'Calculated'` only once - and it does so right before asking for `'Order?'` - after inputting the program ends wihtout any more outputs.

---

More infos:

- [PyTut: classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)
- [Python Class Members Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867219/python-class-members-initialization)
- [Instance variables vs. class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714573/instance-variables-vs-class-variables-in-python)

You can put your "init"-method into a holder-class to avoid polluting global():

```
class A_base:
    @staticmethod
    def calculate_a():
        print("Calculated")
        return 5

class A:   
    a = A_base.calculate_a()
```